# Extract text from column between two delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi all i have pandas columns that are looking like this

```
**<https://stackoverflow.com/> Stackoverflow runs the world --website --q 3** - <@123456789> (today)
```

How can I parse each column to get something like this

```
<https://stackoverflow.com/> Stackoverflow runs the world --website --q 3
```

**or in a perfect world**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/ Stackoverflow runs the world
```

most of the time text after each **--** is different or sometimes there is only one **--**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'website': [
        '**<https://stackoverflow.com/> Stackoverflow runs the world --website --q 3** - <@123456789> (today)',
        '**<https://ddg.com/> Ducks prefer salad --website --q 3** - <@123456789> (today)',
        '**<https://wikipedia.org/> Wikipedia is nice --website --q 3** - <@123456789> (today)',
    ]
})
```

Solution:
Assuming `--website` always occurs after web page title and url is always enclosed like so `**<URL>`

```
df['website_clean'] = (
    df['website']
    .str.replace('--q 3', '--website')
    .str.split('--website').str[0].str[3:]
    .str.replace('> ', ' ').str.strip()
)
```

Output:

```
name    website                                             website_clean
a       **<https://stackoverflow.com/> Stackoverflow r...   https://stackoverflow.com/ Stackoverflow runs t...
b       **<https://ddg.com/> Ducks prefer salad --webs...   https://ddg.com/ Ducks prefer salad
c       **<https://wikipedia.org/> Wikipedia is nice -...   https://wikipedia.org/ Wikipedia is nice
```

Comment: It's working in 70% but I have some strings that have only --q 3 instead of --webiste

Comment: Added quick fix using ```str.replace```